# Second monitor not detecting

Tags: display

I already owned a monitor and my laptop, the monitor had no HDMI in ports, and I already owned a DVI-D dual link to HDMI. So i purchased a DVI-D cord to connect to the converter. I plugged it into my laptop via the HDMI out, and everything worked fine. I used it all day long with no problems. Later I needed to restart my computer due to irrelevant reasons. When my computer came back on my second monitor never show any display. and even before this I used to plug in my laptop to my television and would watch netflix on it. and so to test to make sure it wasnt the cord that I just purchased. I plugged my laptop into the TV, and lo and behold there was no signal. So I came to the conclusion that it has something to do with my display driver. The TV made no physical changes when the HDMI cord was plugged in. Howvever my moniter would show `No signal`
without the cord plugged in (obviously) but when the cord plugs in, it flashes and goes to a black screen as if its about to work and then it says `DVI signal going into sleep mode`

So I went into my screen resolution and clicked 'detect' and it couldnt find anything. So i scoured the internet for a solution. I found a way to update my drivers and I did so. I then rebooted my laptop once more and when it came back on I plugged in the cord once again and the same thing happened. Except this time I hit detect and it detects my monitor, however an error came up saying 'Your resolution is lower than 1020x760' which I know is false because my monitor is larger than my laptop screen so if my laptop reaches the minimum display than my monitor should as well.

I restarted my laptop once more, and this time I couldnt even get the error to come up, I ve tried everything under the sun, and I couldnt find any help anywhere on the internet.

Im sorry if this is really long, but im frustrated and ive been searching the internet for hours on end trying to resolve my problem and now ive found myself here on my knees begging for someone smarter than me

Comment: Is this running Windows or OS X?

Comment: Also, which laptop and graphics solution?

Comment: this is on Windows 8.1

Comment: x64 by the way, im using an HP Envy, and Intel HD Graphics 4000, is the device in my display adapters, if that is what you mean by graphics solution? im sorry im not too sure what you mean by that, and thank you so much guys or the responses!